# Customizing the Inception V3 module

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

How to use the Inception V3 tensorflow module to train with our own requirement dataset images. Say for example I want to train the Inception V3 module with the different cool drinkcompany brands Pepsi, Sprite etc.. How it can be achieved..??
In the link https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception they have explained with the ImageNet. I am bit confused with that. Please explain the stuff.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a tutorial site; it is for help once you have learnt enough to have your own code in place. You would need to look for tutorials elsewhere on the web.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to check Transfer Learning. which consists in retrain only the last layers with new categories

[How to Retrain Inception's Final Layer for New Categories](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining)

Answer (score 0):

Baptiste's answer linking to the Tensorflow site is good. This is a very broad question and his link is a good start.

If you'd like something a little more step-by-step then the [Tensorflow for Poets](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#0) tutorial is basically the same but doesn't require the use of Bazel commands. It initially uses flowers but you can use whatever dataset you want.

There are many other examples and tutorials on the web. I found some more with a quick search including [this page](https://sourcedexter.com/retrain-tensorflow-inception-model/) and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m2D02eZTB4s).

Good Luck!